# Using Google Places API to search for the name of first hotel of a list of coordinates

Tags: python, pandas, api

I am trying to search for the first hotel for each of these coordinates below

```
target_locations = [[-18.3693, 26.5019],
 [51.3813, 1.3862],
 [40.8106, 111.6522],
 [-17.65, -62.75],
 [49.6383, -1.5664],
 [38.4661, 68.8053],
 [43.9098, 67.2495],
 [45.55, 2.3167],
 [55.756, -4.8556]]
```

I tried the following codes

```
target_search = "Hotel"
radius = 5000
base_url = "https://maps.googleapis.com/maps/api/place/nearbysearch/json"
my_params  = {
    "location": target_locations,
    "keyword": target_search,
    "radius": radius,
    "key": g_key
}
# Search for the first hotel in each coordinate
for loc in locations: 
    first_hotels = requests.get(base_url,params = my_params).json()
    time.sleep(1)
```

when I tried to print out each of the hotel's name I got an error.

```
print(first_hotels["results"][0]["name"])
```

**IndexError: list index out of range**

Anyone got any idea what's wrong?  Here is the documentation I used
https://developers.google.com/maps/documentation/places/web-service/search-nearby

Answer (score 2, accepted):

You're defining the parameters outside of the loop, and are passing the entire list `target_locations`. Update the parameters inside the loop:

```
import requests

target_locations = [[-18.3693, 26.5019],
 [51.3813, 1.3862],
 [40.8106, 111.6522],
 [-17.65, -62.75],
 [49.6383, -1.5664],
 [38.4661, 68.8053],
 [43.9098, 67.2495],
 [45.55, 2.3167],
 [55.756, -4.8556]]

target_search = "Hotel"
radius = 5000
base_url = "https://maps.googleapis.com/maps/api/place/nearbysearch/json"

# Search for the first hotel in each coordinate
for loc in target_locations:
    
    my_params  = {
        "location": loc, # pass a single location only
        "keyword": target_search,
        "radius": radius,
        "key": g_key
    }
    
    first_hotels = requests.get(base_url,params = my_params).json()
    time.sleep(1)
```

Comment: Thank you so much sir!!  I can't believe I didn't see it earlier